# switch protonvpn servers every one hour

Tags: bash, shell-script

I am using protonvpn.

My servers looks like:

```
UK#13
US-VA#2
US-CA#1
US-CA#2
US-NJ#9
```

To switch to a server, I have to use `protonvpn c UK#13`.

I want to cycle through the vpn servers in this list sequentially after every one hour infinitely.

In other words, after 1st hour it will run `protonvpn c UK#13`

after 2nd hour it will run `protonvpn c US-VA#2`

after 3rd hour it will run `protonvpn c US-CA#1`

after 4th hour it will run `protonvpn c US-CA#2`

after 5th hour it will run `protonvpn c US-NJ#9`

after 6th hour it will run `protonvpn c UK#13`

after 7th hour it will run `protonvpn c US-VA#2`

after 8th hour it will run `protonvpn c US-CA#1`

.....

How can I do that?

Comment: What have you tried on your own? Where are you stuck? This looks like a simple `for x in $servers` task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also do it with a simple bash script

```
#!/bin/bash

sites=("UK#13" "US-VA#2" "US-CA#1" "US-CA#2" "US-NJ#9")
while true;
do
  for site in ${sites[@]};
  do
    echo "Connecting to $site"
    sleep 1
  done
done
```

Change `sleep 1` to `sleep 3600` and add in your protonvpn command rather than the `echo`.

Answer (score 1):

Simple switch script and a config file run in [cron](https://askubuntu.com/questions/2368/how-do-i-set-up-a-cron-job) or [systemd-timer](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Systemd/Timers) should suffice.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

set -euo pipefail

SWITCHFILE='/tmp/switch'

switch_to="$(head -1 $SWITCHFILE)"
sed -i '1d' "$SWITCHFILE"
echo "$switch_to" >> "$SWITCHFILE"
protonvpn c "$switch_to"
```

config file:

```
UK#13
US-VA#2
US-CA#1
US-CA#2
US-NJ#9
```

Here is the explaination of the scripts working. There is a config file (put it somewhere safer than /tmp) that contains a list of servers you want to cycle through. The script reads the first one and saves it to `$switch_to`. Then it deletes this first line (thats the `sed` command) and appends it to the end of the file. Then it calls protonvpn as requested to switch.